# Codesigning errors while creating Bots?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, codesign, xcode5.1, osx-server

I am trying to Create Bot for my iOS app. I am getting following 3 errors.

```
 Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer: Piscean” were found.

 No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Distribution: Piscean” were found.

 CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

I am new to Bots. Any idea why am i getting this and how can i get rid of these errors. I have added My iOS program to both Xcode and OS X Server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried creating a bot but error is specific to code-signing (its the name of the concept and utility that adds digital signature to the applications).

Codesign requires identity (a certificate/key pair from your keychain) to do this operation.
You can a) try to [add that identity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1618/_index.html) into the keychain  b) Remove codesign'ing from your application by going to Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code signing identity -> Select "Dont code sign"